# Dynamically create Textboxes in Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

This probably is a dupe, but I wasn't able to find the information that would help me produce a solution.

I basically have a Stackpanel, which has a Grid with defined Rows and Columns and I want to dynamically create a set amount of textboxes in differing Rows and Columns, that I can then use to interact with.

My solution up until now was to create every textbox one by one in WPF and then add all of them one by one to a List of Textboxes in C# to interact with them. But I really don't believe that this is a clean solution.

Example WPF

```
<TextBox x:Name="Std2018_01" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="50" TextAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TextChanged="Std2018_TextChanged"></TextBox>
<TextBox x:Name="Std2018_02" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="50" TextAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TextChanged="Std2018_TextChanged"></TextBox>
<TextBox x:Name="Std2018_03" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="50" TextAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TextChanged="Std2018_TextChanged"></TextBox>
```

C# Adding them to a List

```
        boxes2018.Add(Std2018_01);
        boxes2018.Add(Std2018_02);
        boxes2018.Add(Std2018_03);
```

There has to be a better way to solve this.

Comment: You can create them dynamically and specify the position, you need the following steps:
1). Create the new TextBox instance, var textBox = new TextBox()... and set the properties.
2). Using the Grid.SetRow(textBox, index) and Grid.SetColumn(textBox, index) specify the row and column  where to put the new text box.
3). Add the textBox to the specific Grid instance using the MyGrid.Children.Add(textBox);

And you can store them anywhere you want, list, array etc. :)

Comment: This worked like a Charm, didnt work much with Grids yet, so I was missing the Childen-Part. Thanks a lot

Comment: I still have a question though: I am using Visual Studio for working with my application and I really like the Dynamic View of the UI, but there's probably no way to show the dynamically created TextBoxes in that View, right?

Comment: Yes, as they are created runtime they will not appear on the UI editor view.
I would advise to you to use the Editor View whenever possible and create controls dynamically only if it is really necessary (it depends on some user input etc.).
If you know beforehand how many controls do you need even if it seems repetitive add them in the editor otherwise if somebody is onboarding on this project will face the complexity that some controls are created in the code behind and some of them are showing up in the Editor, this can be confusing.